# loadCache() and localLoadCache() and the logic inside cache's storing data

Tags: caching, persistent-storage, ignite

These days I made some experiments about loadCache、localLoadCache and query data from cache. However, I was more and more puzzled. Here are my puzzles. Please help me if you know how to explain.

1. What's the difference between loadCache and localLoadCache?
2. What's the logic inside cache's storing data? For example, I start a node called ''`A`',whose cache stores some data(assume 10 items) from table Person in `DB`. And then inside the code I let it query data from cache per 5 seconds.
   Then I start a new node called '`B`',whose cache stores 20 other items data from table Person in `DB` and also let it query data from cache per 5 seconds. However, why querying data from ‘`A`’ and '`B`' is 30 items data (the sum of 10+20)?
3. If I let `B` put a new item data into cache,and then '`A`' can also query out the new data? When I close `B`, then `A` query out 10 items data, which means it is same as first. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Ignite is a distributed data storage. It partitions your data set and equally distributes it across available nodes. E.g., if you have 30 entries and 2 nodes, you will have approximately 15 entries on each node. The ownership is defined by Ignite automatically, you can't decide where to store a particular entry (well, you can, but this is non-trivial).

Having said that, when a table is loaded into the cache, it is treated as a single data set. When you get an entry from the cache, it will be transparently returned regardless of where it is stored.

As for the loading, the process is the following:

1. Each node independently fetches the whole table from the DB and iterates through rows.
2. For each row the `CacheStore` implementation creates key and value objects and passes them to the cache.
3. Cache decides whether this particular key-value pair belongs to the local node. If yes, it is saved. If not, it is discarded.
4. As a result, the table will be fully stored in the cluster in a distributed fashion and each node will have it's own subset of data.

`localLoadCache` method executes this process on local node only (useful in some specific cases). `loadCache` is basically just a shortcut that broadcasts a closure and calls `localLoadCache` on all nodes, therefore it triggers the distributed data loading.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and kindness. 1.And how cache decides whether the particular key-value pair belongs to the local node? With some algorithms?                                                              2.As you said, loadCache will trigger the distributed data loading.And what about localLoadCache Does it will trigger the distributed data loading?

Comment: 1. Randezvous hashing algorithm is used for this by default: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing. 2. `localLoadCache` loads only locally. But usually it doesn't make sense to load only on one node because you will not load the whole table. The method exists for cases when user for some reason wants to trigger the process on all nodes manually.